# Как вставить ссылку в Popup?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Делаю через popup.js в Popup.html с помощью тега  ссылку,она высвечивается в popup.html,как ссылка,но при нажатии на неё ничего не происходит. Хотя если нажать на неё ПКМ и выбрать открыть в новой вкладке,то всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

После написания сюда меня осенило!Надо было указать атрибут "target=_blank".